# Importing JSON strings via CSV into MySQL. Good or bad?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, csv, import

I'm sitting on a CSV import into a database trying to think of ways to add more data without having to change the API (add new fields).

Since working with JSON quite a bit on the client, I'm thinking of storing data into MYSQL as JSON string. So if I have a field

```
  image_filenames
```

Where I'm currently storing data like this:

```
  img123.jpg
```

WOuld it make sense to store multiple images in a JSON array like so:

```
 {"img_base":"img123.jpg", "img_alt_1":"img123-1.jpg", "img_alt_2":"img123-2" }
```

I can deserialize server side, so it woudn't be much of a problem to grab the image I need from the JSON array, while it does not bloat up the API.

**Question:**
I can't find anything at all on importing CSV with JSON strings. So, what's good and bad in doing so? Are there security concerns (SQL-injections)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a data model scheme that changes or is inconsistent, then the relational database storage isn't the best choice. Sure, you can serialize it and store as binary string, but why? IMO, and I'm not a fan of NoSQLs, but MongoDB looks like something you might make use of. Its document scheme is JSON-based, it'd be familiar to you if you work with JSON-based code on a daily basis. I'd use that to store the data rather than relational db.

Comment: Thanks. My orginial import scheme is pretty basic, but I'm getting a lot of requests to add stuff. If I look at other import APIs they are just bloated with tons of fields, which are at based seldomly used. So my idea was to just store JSON arrays and add support for the seldom fields by allowing array elements such as "img_seldomly_used":"imgXXX.jpg. I haven't looked at MongoDB until now. Can you say in a sentence what the ups/downs of non-relational db are vs relational? Thanks!

Comment: Non-relational ones do less work, so they work faster in some scenarios. They also don't have a scheme, so there's no `alter table` statement, therefore you can add "columns" as much as you like. If you don't have relations and need something to store data in JSON format, but that it can be searchable - MongoDB would be great.

Comment: @N.B. - ok. I have a lot of relations, but still (have been reading up on some stuff) Mongo sounds interesting, too. For now, I'm sticking with MySQL though. I also like the JSON idea, because I will sooner or later have to create some offline functionalities and already having a JSON string to process client side is kind of nice. Anyway, please make your input an answer, so I can check

Comment: Done. Good luck with your project, also if you get the time and if you're interested in having structure-less relational design - google for EAV database model.

Comment: @N.B. Thank you very much. Time is the constriant, but I will check asap :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transferred from comments to here:

If you have a data model scheme that changes or is inconsistent, then the relational database storage isn't the best choice. Sure, you can serialize it and store as binary string, but why? IMO, and I'm not a fan of NoSQLs, but MongoDB looks like something you might make use of. Its document scheme is JSON-based, it'd be familiar to you if you work with JSON-based code on a daily basis. I'd use that to store the data rather than relational db.

Non-relational ones do less work, so they work faster in some scenarios. They also don't have a scheme, so there's no `alter table` statement as such, therefore you can add "columns" as much as you like. If you don't have relations and need something to store data in JSON format, but that it can be searchable - MongoDB would be great.